# Fine-grained authorization (based on business data) in Neo4J

Tags: security, neo4j, authorization

I would like to implement a fine-grained authorization in a Neo4j Database accessed using the default Neo4J REST API.

The business data and the authorization rules will be persisted in the same Graph Database. Every node will have an incoming relationship "CAN_ACCESS" from other nodes representing the application users.

I would like to implement some kind of interceptor having the following behavior, on GET requests:

- Read the authorization header
- Perform the get normally
- Based on the nodes to be returned, check if the user in authorization header has a "CAN_ACCESS" relationship to the retrieved nodes. If the answer is no, then change the response code to 401.

Is there a class in Neo4j Server API I can extend to plug this algorithm into my server? I think I need a single place to handle the request, the response and the retrieved data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can look into overriding the RepresentationFormat for nodes and check in there.

You probably have to register a custom content type for this to work.

Another option is to add a filter to the Neo4j server and re-parse the responses and check there for your security rules.

Perhaps the filter used in the authentication extension can help you as an example:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension/tree/2.0

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm a little confused about how to implement the first solution. The second one is clearer to me, I don't like the re-parse part, but it can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [SecurityRule](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules) for this. A SecurityRule is a filter that any request to the server needs to pass.

Comment: Ok, so how can I get access to the retrieved nodes, from the SecurityRule object? The method isAuthorized does not expose this information.